# Emulating SELECT MAX FROM TABLE with a cursor without using MAX function and ORDER BY

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, database-cursor

i need to emulate this without using MAX function and ORDER BY just using a cursor. I think i have to use FETCH WHILE and FETCH or FOR but didn't have success. I'll aprecciatte some help!

```
SELECT MAX(field) FROM table;
```

The fields are just 4 random letters (A,B,C,D)

Table fields are:

```
A |  
B |  
C |  
D |
```

Comment: Is this a programming exercise? Why can't you just select the max into a variable?

Comment: It's impossible to say why your code "didn't have success." when we can't see that code.  Why do you want to not use MAX?

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to loop over your value set, you would just keep a running maximum value.  The following pattern can be adapted for your purposes:

```sql
DECLARE
  l_cMax my_table.field%TYPE;
  l_bFirstPass BOOLEAN := TRUE;
  CURSOR c_fieldValues IS
    SELECT m.field
    FROM my_table m;
BEGIN
  FOR rec IN c_fieldValues LOOP
    IF l_bFirstPass THEN
      l_cMax := rec.field;
      l_bFirstPass := FALSE;
    ELSIF rec.field > l_cMax THEN
      l_cMax := rec.field;
    END IF;
  END LOOP;
  dbms_output.put_line('Maximum Value is: '||l_cMax);
END;
/
```

Comment: Thank you, that helped a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need PL/SQL (unless you're practicing how to use it). SQL can be enough. Have a look at some examples:

Sample data:

```
SQL> select * From test;

C
-
A
B
C
D
```

One option:

```
SQL> select a.col
  2  from test a left join test b on a.col < b.col and b.col is not null
  3  where b.col is null;

C
-
D

SQL>
```

And another:

```
SQL> select a.col
  2  from test a
  3  where a.col not in (select b.col
  4                      from test b join test c on b.col < c.col
  5                     );

C
-
D

SQL>
```